# Some questions about the spectral composition of a nonnegative self-adjoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, self-adjoint-operators

Let $H$ be a $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space and $(H_\lambda)_{\lambda\ge0}$ be a spectral decomposition of $H$ (see below). Now, let $$\mathcal D\left(A_\varphi\right):=\left\{x\in H:\int_0^\infty\varphi(\lambda)\:{\rm d}\langle\pi_\lambda x,x\rangle_H<\infty\right\}$$ and $$\langle A_\varphi x,y\rangle_H:=\color{red}{\varphi(0)\langle\pi_0 x,y\rangle_H}+\int_0^\infty\varphi(\lambda)\:{\rm d}\langle\pi_\lambda x,y\rangle_H\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in\mathcal D\left(A_\varphi\right)\text{ and }y\in H\tag1$$ for Borel measurable $\varphi:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$.

> **Question 1**: I can vaguely imagine that it's possible to define a operator by duality, but why exactly does $(1)$ yield a well-defined (symmetric?) linear operator $\left(\mathcal D\left(A_\varphi\right),A_\varphi\right)$? Moreover, sometimes I've seen $A_\varphi$ defined without the red term on the right-hand side of $(1)$. Can anybody explain this to me?
>
> **Question 2**: Depending on the answer to the first question, I get that $\left(\mathcal D\left(A_\varphi\right),A_\varphi\right)$ is symmetric. Can we show that it is even self-adjoint (for any (possibly unbounded) Borel measurable $\varphi$)?

Now, if I got it correctly, if $(\mathcal D(A),A)$ is a nonnegative self-adjoint operator on $H$, $(H_\lambda)_{\lambda\ge0}$ can be chosen such that $$A_{\operatorname{id}_{[0,\:\infty)}}=A\tag2.$$

> **Question 3**: Is this correct under the given assumptions? Sometimes I've seen that $H$ is assumed to be separable. Moreover, sometimes I've seen that $\bigcup_{\lambda\ge0}H_\lambda=H$ is assumed. Is this always possible?

---

### **Definitions**:

> $(H_\lambda)_{\lambda\ge0}$ is called *spectral decomposition of $H$* if
>
> 1. $H_\lambda$ is a closed subspace of $H$ for all $\lambda\ge0$
> 2. $(H_\lambda)_{\lambda\ge0}$ is nondecreasing and *right-continuous*, i.e. $$\bigcap_{\mu>\lambda}=H_\lambda\;\;\;\text{for all }\lambda\ge0$$
> 3. $\bigcup_{\lambda\ge0}H_\lambda$ is dense

Let $\pi_\lambda$ denote the orthogonal projection of $H$ onto $H_\lambda$ for $\lambda\ge0$. It can be shown that

4. $[0,\infty)\ni\lambda\mapsto\pi_\lambda$ is *nondecreasing*, i.e. $$\langle\pi_\lambda x,x\rangle_H\le\langle\pi_\mu x,x\rangle_H\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in H,$$ and right-continuous (with respect to the strong operator topology)

So,

5. $[0,\infty)\ni\lambda\mapsto\langle\pi_\lambda x,x\rangle_H=\left\|\pi_\lambda x\right\|_H^2$ is bounded (by $\left\|x\right\|_H^2)$, nondecreasing and right-continuous for all $x\in H$
6. $[0,\infty)\ni\lambda\mapsto\langle\pi_\lambda x,y\rangle_H=2^{-1}\left(\langle\pi_\lambda(x+y),x+y\rangle_H-\langle\pi_\lambda x,x\rangle_H-\langle\pi_\lambda y,y\rangle_H\right)$ is right-continuous and of bounded variation for all $x,y\in H$

Comment: 1) Without the red term, you're simply defining $\phi(H)$ in the sense of the [Borel functional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_functional_calculus) on $H$; in particular, at least when the real-valued function $\phi$ is bounded on bounded subsets of the spectrum of $H$, you get that $\phi(H)$ is actually self-adjoint.

Comment: 2) With the red term, you're getting $\phi(0)P_{\ker H} + \phi(H)$, where $P_{\ker H}$ is the orthogonal projection onto $\ker H$; if $\phi(H)$ is self-adjoint, then $\phi(0)P_{\ker H} + \phi(H)$ is a perturbation of the self-adjoint operator $\phi(H)$ by the bounded self-adjoint operator $\phi(0)P_{\ker H}$, so that by the [Kato–Rellich theorem](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~loss/14SPRINGTEA/katorellich.pdf), the operator $\phi(0)P_{\ker H} + \phi(H)$ is also self-adjoint.

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić 1) Thank you for your comments. I'm used to note the range of a function $\phi$ defined on a set $H$ by $\phi(H)$, but I've got the feeling that you notate something else with it. Could you clarify? 2) So, with the red term, $\left(\mathcal D\left(A_\varphi\right),A_\varphi\right)$ doesn't need to be self-adjoint?

Comment: If $T$ is a linear transformation on a complex vector space $V$ and $f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k z^k$ is a polynomial, then one simply defines $f(T) := \sum_{k=0}^n a_k T^k$. If $T$ is an unbounded self-adjoint operator and $\phi$ is a Borel function on $\mathbb{R}$, then the black term is how you have to *define* $\phi(T)$ in this greater generality; if $\phi$ is a real polynomial, then this construction of $\phi(T)$ reduces to the naive construction of $\phi(T)$ (modulo domain issues).

Comment: These kinds of constructions are called [functional calculi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_calculus)—a linear transformation on a complex vector space has a polynomial functional calculus, an arbitrary bounded operator on a Banach space admits a [holomorphic functional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_functional_calculus), a normal bounded operator on a Hilbert space admits a [continuous functional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_functional_calculus) (by the appropriate spectral theorem)…

Comment: …and an unbounded self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space admits a [Borel functional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_functional_calculus). With regard to your second question, under very mild assumptions on $\phi$, the operator $\phi(H)$ defined by the black term is guaranteed to be self-adjoint, so that by Kato–Rellich, your operator $A_\phi$, which is just a perturbation of a self-adjoint operator by a bounded self-adjoint operator (the red term), is also guaranteed to be self-adjoint.